# Como consumir API autenticada no Laravel com VueJS?

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js

Preciso consumir uma API com VueJs no Laravel 5.2, mas ela está autenticada, alguma dica para este processo ?

Comment: Mikaell, bem vindo ao Soft, consulte o Ajuda e faça o Tour para entender como funciona esta comunidade e como perguntar aqui. Coloque parte do teu código para podermos entender e analisar o seu problema.

Answer (score 5):

Não é comum uma API usar autenticação tradicional por session. O que se costuma ter como proteção é um servidor OAuth ou autenticação por JSON Web Token.

Caso a forma de autenticação não possa ser modificada, então seus componentes Vue precisam ser servidos através das rotas do Laravel junto com as views do próprio Laravel, tudo isso após o usuário se autenticar na aplicação. A partir daí qualquer chamada à API não seria barrada pela autenticação, que já foi feita e o usuário logado está na Session.

Neste caso você teria uma aplicação híbrida.